# return in boolean method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

this is a boolean method which is a small part of my assignment. I want to return true or false base on if there is a match between a input and the record. I think i met a syntax problem.

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[]param) {
    for(String s: param)
    {
        for(Residents r: petshop)
        {
            if(s.equals(r.getPhone()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }       
}
```

this is the code of the method, but there are always red line indicating that i should add return into the code, otherwise change the method into void. But I already add return true inside the if statement.

Comment: add a `return false;` after the loops

Comment: `return false;` at the end.

Comment: If there is no match, then there is no code path leading to a return statement. That's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: what is `petshop` ? Also , as said by others, you need to return a value in case of `param` or `petshop` are empty or no match so add that in the end of method , `return false` .

Answer (score 6):

As the comments already stated, you need an additional `return` because every method with a non-void return type require each possible path to have a return value.

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[] param)
{
    for (String s : param) {
        for (Residents r : petshop) {
            if (s.equals(r.getPhone())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `return false;` outside the for loop so that the method has a return statement in all possible conditions. This means that even if the method execution never finds a match, even then the method should be able to return a boolean value, i.e. false which means it didn't find any match.

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[] param)
{
    for (String s : param) {
        for (Residents r : petshop) {
            if (s.equals(r.getPhone())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // This is the fix
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the state `true` inside the if loop with a variable and then return that variable at the end of the loop.

Please refer the following one:

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[] param) {
    boolean state;
    for (String s: param) {
        for (Residents r: petshop) {
            if (s.equals(r.getPhone())) {
                state = true;
            }
        }

    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Note that this still won't compile, because you forgot to initialize `state`.

Comment: This is slow because it checks every pair every time, as opposed to returning as soon as a check succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can declare a `boolean retVal = false` and set it to true in case `s.equals(r.getPhone())` but always return this variable.

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[] param) {
    // declare the return value
    boolean retVal = false;
    for (String s : param) {
        for (Residents r : petshop) {
            if (s.equals(r.getPhone())) {
                retVal = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The difference to @maio290's solution is the loop always running completely, no matter if the condition was met at some element or not. This may become a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in case your if condition does not get true then you are not returning anything. 
Refer this.

```
public boolean checkPhone(String[] param) {
   boolean isMatch = false;
      for (String s: param) {
         for (Residents r: petshop) {
           if (s.equals(r.getPhone())) {
              isMatch = true;
           }
         }

     }
   return isMatch ;
}
```

Comment: This is the third answer proposing a version of this approach - but it is slower than returning immediately because it is not short-circuiting.